# Run a supervisord program conditionally

Tags: supervisord

Lets say I have two programs in supervisord. Is there a way to run the first program (background process) conditionally without having to move that to a separate script file?

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log

#Need this program to run conditionally - say based off an environment variable being set
[program:prog1]
command=/bin/prog1

[program:prog2]
command=/bin/prog2 -DFOREGROUND
```

Answer (score 5):

Resurrecting an old thread, but @nelson's answer is incomplete. Namely, environment variables in supervisor need to be formatted as `%(ENV_YOURVARIABLE)s` in order to be recognized (notice the prefix `ENV_`, `%` sign before brackets and `s` at the end). Additionally, you have to export it before sending it to bash script:

```
[program:prog1]
command=bash -c "export INIT_PROG=%(ENV_INIT_PROG)s  && ./conditional-startup.sh"
```

conditional-startup.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $INIT_PROG = "some value" ]; then
    /bin/prog1
fi
```

**See also:**

- [Supervisor configuration](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html)

Answer (score 3):

Pass conditional value to *SERVER1_START* and control the flow.

```
[program:somecommand]
command=bash -c "if [ ${SERVER1_START} = "VALUE-X" ]; then /apps/bin/start.sh 
/apps/server.properties; fi"
```